# How can I read this Struct object in python?

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

I'm currently programming with the dialogflow library for python, but when I get the list of parameters I get from an attempt, it returns me a Struct object that I don't know how to read.

```
 fields {
  key: "apellido1"
  value {
    string_value: "Baena"
  }
}
fields {
  key: "apellido2"
  value {
    string_value: "P\303\251rez"
  }
}
fields {
  key: "nombre"
  value {
    string_value: "Rub\303\251n"
  }
}
```

the documentation of the dialogflow library is very limited and there are no examples.

The best I can guess is that Struct is from the following route

```
google.protobuf.struct_pb2
```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

There are Dialogflow samples up on Github, the following are the Python-related samples: [weather sample](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-weather-python) using WWO API and a [translation sample](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-translate-python). In general though, the Dialogflow [documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents/actions-parameters) discusses how to access parameters off an intent. A snippet from the weather sample below:

```
import json
from flask import Flask, request, make_response, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)
log = app.logger

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    req = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)

    try:
        action = req.get('queryResult').get('action')
    except AttributeError:
        return 'json error'

    if action == 'weather':
        res = weather(req)
    elif action == 'weather.activity':
        res = weather_activity(req)
    elif action == 'weather.condition':
        res = weather_condition(req)
    elif action == 'weather.outfit':
        res = weather_outfit(req)
    elif action == 'weather.temperature':
        res = weather_temperature(req)
    else:
        log.error('Unexpected action.')

    print('Action: ' + action)
    print('Response: ' + res)

    return make_response(jsonify({'fulfillmentText': res}))

def weather(req):
    parameters = req['queryResult']['parameters']
    print('Dialogflow Parameters:')
    print(json.dumps(parameters, indent=4))

    .....
```